# Return only one sentence based on the words found in array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a Java code that will retrieve sentences based on the array of words. 
String of text:

```
String text = "This is a sample text. Simple yet elegant. Everyone dies. I don't care. This text is nice.";
```

I also have an array of words as below:

```
String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};
```

Now, I need to get the sentences that contains the specific word in the array. So, the sentences to be outputted should contain either the word "text" , "care" or "nice" . The resultant output should be as below:

```
This is a sample text. //contains the word "text"
I don't care. //contains the word "care"
This text is nice. //contains the word "text" and "nice"
```

The code that I have is:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String text = "This is a sample text. Simple yet elegant. Everyone dies. I don't care. This text is nice.";
    String[] words = new String[] {"text", "care", "nice"};
    String[] parts = text.split("\\.");

    for(String w: words){
        for(String sentence: parts){
            if(sentence.contains(w)){
                System.out.println(sentence +" //contains: "+w);
            }
        }
    }   
}
```

However, if the sentence contains two words from the array, it will print the sentence twice. For instance:

```
The text is nice //contains: text
The text is nice//contains: nice.
```

How do I print the sentence only once? 
Thanks.

Comment: So when you print the sentence only once, do you want all the words that it contains to be printed as well?

Comment: Yes, only retrieve the sentences with the specified word in the array and list all words found in the sentences.

Comment: Posted my answer. Have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java 8 solution.

```
    for (String sentence : parts) {

        List<String> wordsInCurrentSentence = new LinkedList<String>();

        for (String w : words) {
            if (sentence.contains(w)) {
                wordsInCurrentSentence.add(w);
            }
        }

        if (!wordsInCurrentSentence.isEmpty()) {
            String result = wordsInCurrentSentence.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(","));
            System.out.println(sentence.trim() + " //contains: " + result);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to put the outer loop in. That way you can check if your wanted words are hit and add them to a local list. Something like this:

```
for(String sentence: parts){

    List<String> hitList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(String w: words){
        if(sentence.contains(w)){
            hitList.add(w);
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sentence +" //contains: "+ hitList != null ? hitList : "No match" );
}
```

This way you can che for cases like the one you pointed out up **This text is nice. //contains the word "text" and "nice"**

Comment: If we put the check for hitAlready first, we can skip the call to contains(), right?

Comment: I edited the code, because the one I had would not print out all of the hit words, only the first one. And from what you wrote, you would like to be able to print all of your hits.

Comment: The change I did suits better your case and what you desire. You save all the hits in the list, and after the comparison, you just write/show them.

Comment: Just add a check that the hitList is not empty before you print it, and you'll get my +1.

Answer (score 1):

Reverse the loop and add break. There are better ways of doing this which are suggested by others already. But with small change in your code it should work. Swap the loops and add break on success.

```
for(String sentence: parts){
        for(String w: words){
            if(sentence.contains(w)){
                System.out.println(sentence +" //contains: "+w);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go it using regex like:

```
String regex = ".*?(" + String.join("|", words) + ").*?";//either of one word in the sentence
for (String sentence: parts) {
    if(sentence.matches(regex)) {
        //...
    }
}
```